# Protractor Mac installation Issue - protractor --version zsh: command not found: protractor

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, protractor, ui-automation

I'm interested in using Protractor for e2e testing. But running into some possible installation issues on a Mac(macOS Catalina). The main problem I'm having is when trying to verify Protractor's version from the command line. I get the following message when entering protractor --version, zsh: command not found: protractor.

Installation steps:

Step 1 : Download and install node.js
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
verified node -v v14.17.0
verified npm -v. 6.14.13

Step 2 : Install Protractor

-verify npm install -g protractor

-Cannot verify protractor --version. I get this message: zsh: command not found: protractor.

I know how to solve this issue on a windows laptop. But have no idea how to on a mac. Thanks for any help.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRAbt.png)

Comment: There are a lot answers here. Did you instal node.js? Did you install protractor globally?

Comment: @GajJulije, yes, I installed node.js and protractor globally.  I verified node -v v14.17.0 and verified npm -v. 6.14.13. Let me know if you want me to try something new. Thanks 

I Installed Protractor as follow: 

npm install -g protractor

Comment: One more thing you should know before you enter in protractor world is that protractor support is ended already or it will end with this year. So many companies migrating to other frameworks... I will check is there something else that can help you

Comment: Interesting. Any other automation framework you recommend for angular applications?

Comment: Cypress or Playwright

Answer (score 0):

The option `-g` in `npm install -g protractor` results the protractor is installed to npm global package location, so you need to append the location into `PATH` environment, otherwise OS can't find it.

You can get that location from `prefix` of cmd `npm config list` output.

Or you config global package location to you desired folder by `npm config prefix <a absolute folder path>`, then append the folder path into `PATH` environment, run `npm install -g protractor`